# Searching for strings contained in file1 that are NOT FOUND in file2

Tags: linux, string, search, grep, findstr

I'm trying to run a search command to lookup strings from file1 and find them in file2. I then want to print ONLY the strings from file1 that are NOT FOUND in file2.

File1 would be something like:

```
 read
 write
 access
```

File2 would be:

```
0xFF88 T write
0xFF87 t xyzwrite
0xFF86 T read
0xFF85 T xyzread
0xFF84 T xyzaccess
```

So the desired result would be:

```
 access
```

*** Note, I did add a blank to all of the strings in File1 in order to not include every occurrence of the string which is part of another string.

I've tried:

```
grep -vf file1 file2
```

and get results from file2 that are all but the write and read lines, addresses included.

I've tried:

```
grep -vf file2 file1
```

and get all of file1 because a whole line of file2 never appears in file1.

I've tried:

```
diff file1 file2 | grep \^|<
```

and get all of file1 proceeded with < on each line.

I was told that if I could remove the first 8 characters of each line in file2 then the diff/grep commands would work.

I've also tried findstr (Windows) with various options and again, I can't get it to work.

Also, please note that each file has many more lines than I've shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: if file1 has other text than shown, please add dummy strings, else solution given might not work for you... and clarify which columns between file1 and file2 are to be compared..

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to do a loop:

```
for i in $(cat File1); do
  grep -q "\<$i\$" File2 || echo $i
done
```

This will print out:

```
access
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The above prints $i every time so it essentially prints all of File1. I am a little confused though because it seems the first few print nothing but then prints everything and all of the leading blanks are removed.

Comment: Do you have trailing spaces in File2? That could cause it. One solution: `grep -q "\<$i *\$" File2`